# CloudKit Data Management

Tags: swift, cloudkit

How to secure that all data related to a customer will be deleted from CloudKit when the user removes the app from his iPhone?

I got an app that saves data to a public CloudKit DB with a reference to a userID. But I don't know how to manage the data when someone deletes the app.

But I am sure there must be a possibility to manage dead data.

Comment: Why would you delete the data when the user deletes the app? The user might have the app on more than one device. Or the user may reinstall the app and expect their data to still be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to detect when a user has removed his app. What you can do is that you update a timestamp in your user record for when the app was used last. Then you could create a procedure that queries all users that have not used the app for more than ... (6 months?) And then delete all related data.

You probably don't want that procedure inside your app. You could create an admin app that connects to the same container. You will be able to access the same production container if you do an ad-hoc distribution to yourself. Or you could use the web api to do this.

Comment: I would app to Edwin's answer. Put a check in the app that logs in cloud kit everytime somebody users it. That way you can be sure you get your man/woman when your looking for zombies.